# Web Parser Problems

Tags: html, parsing, jsoup

I'm fairly new at Java, so I apologize for my lack of a large amount of the subject matter at this point. I'm attempting to code an html parser which analyzes and returns data from the elements from this URL: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurons.

I keep getting this error message when I run the program:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.FileNotFoundException: src/product.txt`: (No such file or directory)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:120)
    at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.load(DataUtil.java:36)
    at org.jsoup.Jsoup.parse(Jsoup.java:88)
    at ParserPractice2.main(ParserPractice2.java:16)
```

My current code looks like this:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.parser.*;
public class ParserPractice2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        File input = new File ("src/product.txt`:");

        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neurons");

        Element content = doc.getElementById("bodyContent");
    }}*

Any help/feedback would be greatly appreciated by this noobie =)Thanks!
```

Comment: Do you know what that error means?

Answer (score 1):

This file doesn't exist:

```
new File ("src/product.txt`:");
```

Perhaps you meant `"src/product.txt"`?